# function prototype and array parameters

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

I'm learning C++ syntax and I got to the point where I'm looking into arrays.
I would like to ask you a question but first let me recap so I know that I got this stuff straight.
I know that you can define a variable as an array with the following syntax:

```
<base type> name [<size(constexpr)>]
```

(the size being part of the type of the array).
This would give me an array of *size* elements of *base type*
If I wanted an array of pointers to the *base type* I could just add a * after the base type specifier as in normal pointer declaration.

```
<base type> *name [<size(constexpr)>]
```

I can't define an array of references because aray are supposed to hold only objects ( and references are just aliases).

Now, if I wanted to declare a reference or a pointer to an array I could use this syntax:

```
<base type> (&name) [<size(constexpr)>]
```

or

```
<base type> (*name) [<size(constexpr)>]
```

So far it is all clear.
What I also know, is that I can pass an array as an argument to a function, but that call will always be interpreted as I am passing a pointer to the array's elements type.
A function that is declared as follows:

```
void f(int array[10])
```

is the same as:

```
void f(int array[])
void f(int *p)
```

and whenever I call this function I am always passing a int* (passing by value).

Question:
what if I wanted to write the function prototype (a pure declaration) without using the parameter's name? I know that I can ordinarily omit parameter names in that case (I could write `void f(int*)` but what about the other two declarations?).And more importantly, what if the parameter is a reference or a pointer to an array?

```
void f(int (&array)[])
```

or

```
void f(int (*array)[])
```

thanks!

Comment: Hace you tried to just omit the name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is perfectly fine:

```
void f(int[])
void f(int*)
```

This is as well:

```
void f(int (*)[])
```

Pointer is a pointer. In this case it points to an array, but it is still a pointer.

However, this is not allowed:

```
void f(int (&)[])
```

No matter if name is specified or not. This declares parameter as "reference to array of an unknown bound", which is not allowed. If you want to receive reference to array of an unknown size, you can use templates for that:

```
template <size_t N>
void f(int (&array)[N]);
```

It is perfectly valid. Of course, fixed-size array (sized at compile time) can also appear without a name:

```
void f(int (&)[32]) //Ok
```

Comment: couldn't I just add the size explicitly?

Comment: Yes, you can. But in this case we go back to fixed-size arrays, for which everything works as usual. I added this point to my answer.